# how to create box with sliding linked images

Tags: language-agnostic

Where can I read more about creating linked slides like at the top of nytimes.com, slate.com, yahoo.com, nyu.edu, etc.  I assume it's javascript, but I'm not sure what it's called, so I'm not sure how to look it up.  I want to create a box at the top of a website with blocks of html text which slide in sequence if the user clicks next or after a certain amount of time.

Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Javascript then you can use [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) and then animate the carousel with setTimeout

But you really need to know some javascript to do this

Answer (score 1):

The jquery cycle plugin is exactly what you are looking for.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Specifically, checkout the advanced demos with paging.